# $a,b,c\ge 0:ab+bc+ca=1.$ Prove that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+bc}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{b+ca}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{c+ab}}\ge 2\sqrt{2}.$

Tags: inequality

Problem. Let $a,b,c\ge 0:ab+bc+ca=1.$ Prove that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+bc}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{b+ca}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{c+ab}}\ge 2\sqrt{2}.$$
Equality holds when two of $a,b,c$ very near $0$.

The form of problem is quite similar with Pham Kim Hung's inequality ([AOPSlink](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h51089p24385918)) and a problem I have posted recently ([similarMSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4703001/if-a-b-c-ge-0-abbcca-1-find-min-p-frac1-sqrt2abc-frac1-sqrt2))

In the post #46, Michael Rozenberg (aka arqady) gave a very sharp Holder estimate.

They are two same equality case. That why I tried to use similar Holder approach:
\begin{align*}
    \left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+bc}}\right)^2\sum_{cyc}(a+bc)(b+c)^3(3a+b+c)^3&\geq\left(\sum_{cyc}(b+c)(3a+b+c)\right)^3\\&=8\left(\sum_{cyc}(a^2+4ab)\right)^3
\end{align*}Hence, we need to prove:$$\left(\sum_{cyc}(a^2+4ab)\right)^3\geq\sum_{cyc}(a+bc)(b+c)^3(3a+b+c)^3,$$hay$$\left((a+b+c)^2+2\right)^3$$
$$ \geq (a+bc)(b+c)^3(3a+b+c)^3+(b+ca)(a+c)^3(3b+a+c)^3+(c+ba)(b+a)^3(3c+b+a)^3,$$
which is wrong when $a=b\rightarrow 0;c\rightarrow +\infty !$

I am trying to find a good Holder estimate.

If you find something interesting in using Holder (like tricks, the motivations...) please share me. Thank you.

Comment: Lagrange Mutliper is the quickest in such situations.

Comment: Could you tell more detail ?

Comment: Well keep track on my website,  I will give many solved examples of Lagrange.

Comment: Please send me link. Thank you.

Comment: For sure,  I will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope, the following will help.

By AM-GM $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+bc}}=\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{a+bc}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{(a+bc)(b+ac)}}\right)}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{a+bc}+\frac{4}{a+bc+b+ac}\right)}=\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{a+bc}+\frac{4}{(a+b)(1+c)}\right)}$$ and it's enough to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{a+bc}+\frac{4}{(a+b)(1+c)}\right)\geq8.$$
If we'll prove that it's enough to prove the last inequality in two cases:

1. $abc=0$;
2. Two variables are equal,

so we can end a proof.

Indeed, for $c=0$ and $ab=1$ by AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{a+bc}+\frac{4}{(a+b)(1+c)}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{ab}+4\left(\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{a(1+b)}+\frac{1}{b(1+a)}\right)=$$
$$=a+b+1+4\left(\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{a+1}+\frac{1}{b+1}\right)=$$
$$=a+b+\frac{4}{a+b}+1+4\cdot\frac{2+a+b}{2+a+b}\geq4+1+4=9>8.$$
Also, for $b=a$ and $c=\frac{1-a^2}{2a},$ where $0<a<1$ we need to prove that
$$a(8a^7-12a^6-21a^5+41a^4-14a^3-10a^2+15a+1)\geq0,$$ which is true because
$$8a^7-12a^6-21a^5+41a^4-14a^3-10a^2+15a+1=$$
$$=a^4(8a^3-12a^2-21a+32)+\left(3a^2-\frac{7}{3}a+\frac{1}{3}\right)^2+\frac{(1-a)(157a+8)}{9}\geq0.$$

Comment: What a beautiful solution! Thank you very much @Michael Rozenberg. It is just a little typo in first line $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+bc}}$.

Comment: @Trần Nk Trang Thank you, I fixed. Now, we need to prove that it's enough to check two cases about them I said.

Comment: We see that it is equivalent to $$f(w^3)=kw^6+A(u,v^2)w^3+B(u,v^2)\ge 0$$where $k<0$. Am I in right way ?

Comment: @Trần Nk Trang I can't got it. Maybe I am wrong. I'll check it again later.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake.

Comment: I don't see how to apply uvw idea ?

Comment: @Trần Nk Trang I tried, but without success. I am very busy in last time. I'll try more later.

Comment: I think, we have $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a+bc}\ge 3$$ and we need to prove $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{(a+b)(c+1)}\ge \frac{5}{4}$$

Comment: The last inequality is wrong for $a\rightarrow+\infty$: we obtain $1\geq\frac{5}{4}.$

Answer (score 2):

I hope the following will help.

By AM-GM $$\sqrt{2(a+bc)}\le a+bc+\frac{1}{2},$$hence we will prove$$\frac{1}{2a+2bc+1}+\frac{1}{2b+2ca+1}+\frac{1}{2c+2ab+1}\ge 1.$$
The last inequality was [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349577/prove-frac12a2bc1-frac12b2ca1-frac12c2ab1-ge-1?noredirect=1)