# If $ab+bc+ca=1,$ prove $\frac{\sqrt{a+1}}{a+bc}+\frac{\sqrt{b+1}}{b+ca}+\frac{\sqrt{c+1}}{c+ab}\ge 1+2\sqrt{2}.$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> **Problem.** Let $a,b,c$ be non-negative real numbers satisfying $ab+bc+ca=1.$ Prove that
> $$\frac{\sqrt{a+1}}{a+bc}+\frac{\sqrt{b+1}}{b+ca}+\frac{\sqrt{c+1}}{c+ab}\ge 1+2\sqrt{2}.$$

---

I've tried to use Holder inequality without success.

$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{a+1}}{a+bc}\right)^2.\sum_{cyc}(a+1)^2(a+bc)^2\ge [a+b+c+3]^3. \tag{1}$$

$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{a+1}}{a+bc}\right)^2.\sum_{cyc}(a+1)^2(a+bc)^2(b+c)^3\ge \left(\sum_{cyc}(a+1)(b+c)\right)^3.\tag{2} $$

Which are both leads to wrong inequalities in general.

> I'd like to ask two questions.

1. **Is there a better Holder using ?**

I think the appropriate one might be ugly but if you find it, please feel free to share it here.

2. **Are there others idea which are smooth enough?**

For example, Mixing variables, AM-GM or Cauchy-Schwarz...etc.

I aslo hope to see a good lower bound of $\frac{\sqrt{a+1}}{a+bc},$ which eliminates the radical form (may be the rest is simpler by $uvw$)

All ideas and comments are welcomed. Thank you for your interest!

*Remark.* About $uvw$, see [here.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h278791)

Comment: I checked (1) is true

Comment: @above How about is the result when a=b-> 0?

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4720316/a-b-c-ge-0abbcca-1-prove-that-frac1-sqrtabc-frac1-sqrtbca?rq=1

Comment: The idea with $x^2+y^2+z^2+k\sum\limits_{cyc}x^2y^2+mx^2y^2z^2\geq5+8k+4m$ does not help.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Do you use Holder inequality?

Comment: It quits very ugly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Some thoughts.**

*Remark*: All results are verified by *Mathematica*.

**Fact 1.** Let $x, y, z \ge 0$ with
$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \ge 5$
and $x^2y^2 + y^2z^2 + z^2x^2 + \frac32x^2y^2z^2 \ge 14$. Then $x + y + z \ge 1 + 2\sqrt 2$.

Let
$$x = \frac{\sqrt{a + 1}}{a + bc}, \quad
y = \frac{\sqrt{b + 1}}{b + ca}, \quad
z = \frac{\sqrt{c + 1}}{c + ab}.$$

We have
$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \ge 5$
and $x^2y^2 + y^2z^2 + z^2x^2 + \frac32x^2y^2z^2 \ge 14$.

By Fact 1, we have $x + y + z \ge 1 + 2\sqrt 2$.

Comment: This way is beautiful. We can use contradiction method and Schur to prove the fact.

Comment: I tried to use AM-GM: $$\frac{\sqrt{a+1}}{a+bc}=\frac{a+1}{a+bc}.\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+1}}.$$Now, we'll find suitable yield $2\sqrt{a+1}.f(a,b,c)\le a+1+f^2(a,b,c),$ which savesoccuring equality. I failed here.

Answer (score 2):

**Some thoughts.**

WLOG, assume that $a \ge b \ge c$.

By AM-GM, we have
$\sqrt{a+1} = \frac{2(a + 1)\sqrt 2}{2\sqrt{a + 1}\sqrt{2}}
\ge \frac{2(a + 1)\sqrt 2}{(a + 1) + 2}$.
Also, we have $(1 + c) - (1 + c/3)^2 = \frac19 c(3 - c)\ge 0$
which results in $\sqrt{1 + c} \ge 1 + c/3$. It suffices to prove that
$$
\frac{2(a + 1)\sqrt 2}{(a + 3)(a + bc)}
+ \frac{2(b + 1)\sqrt 2}{(b + 3)(b + ca)}
+ \frac{1 + c/3}{c + ab} \ge 1 + 2\sqrt 2$$
or
$$\frac{3 - 3ab - 2c}{3(c + ab)}
\ge \left(2 - \frac{2(a + 1)}{(a + 3)(a + bc)}
- \frac{2(b + 1)}{(b + 3)(b + ca)}\right)\sqrt 2. \tag{1}$$

Since $3 - 3ab - 2c = 1 - ab + (2 - 2c) > 0$, we only need to prove the case that $\mathrm{RHS}_{(1)} > 0$. Since $\sqrt 2 < \frac{10}{7}$, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{3 - 3ab - 2c}{3(c + ab)}
\ge \left(2 - \frac{2(a + 1)}{(a + 3)(a + bc)}
- \frac{2(b + 1)}{(b + 3)(b + ca)}\right)\cdot \frac{10}{7}. \tag{2}$$
(2) is true which can be verified by *Mathematica*.

Comment: It's interesting. Thank you.

Comment: @RiverLi we have a nice bound ie $$\sqrt{x+1}\geq \frac{x+1}{\frac{x}{6}+2-\frac{1}{\frac{x}{3}+1}},\forall x\ge 0$$

Comment: @ErikSatie Yes, it is good to find a uniform bound. You can write down your proof.

Comment: Well it's very ugly now I have : $$\sqrt{x+1}\geq \left(1+\frac{51}{2\sqrt{2}}-18\right)\frac{\left(x+1\right)}{2+\frac{x}{6}-\frac{1}{\frac{x}{3}+1}}-\left(1+\frac{x}{3}\right)\left(\frac{51}{2\sqrt{2}}-18\right)-\frac{\left|x\left(x-1\right)\left(x-3\right)\right|}{\left(x+3\right)^{3}},\forall x\geq 0$$ which is too complicated for a proof .But it's uniform .

Comment: @ErikSatie When applying your bound for the inequality, I checked and it seems not true. Did you check it?

Comment: @RiverLi I don't check but it's not a surprise since there is absolute value try with (as in my answer ) with : $$\frac{\left(1+\left(\frac{51}{2\sqrt{2}}-18\right)\right)\left(x+1\right)}{2+\frac{x}{6}-\frac{1}{\frac{x}{3}+1}}-\left(\frac{51}{2\sqrt{2}}-18\right)\left(1+\frac{x}{3}\right)-\frac{3}{4}\frac{x}{\left(x+3\right)^{3}}\left(\frac{2x}{x+1}-1\right)^{2}\left(3-x\right)\leq \sqrt{x+1},\forall x\geq 0$$

Comment: @ErikSatie Yesterday I checked this lower bound of $\sqrt{x + 1}$ (in your answer). It seems not true. Did you check it?

Comment: @RiverLi Yes you are right it's corrected now a small mistake thanks you very much ! Now have you an idea to show it ? Feel free to use the inequality .

Comment: @ErikSatie You may write the detailed solution. Now it is far from a solution.

Comment: @RiverLi Buffalo's way can work ?

Comment: @ErikSatie BW is powerful.

Comment: @RiverLi So I stop here .Thanks for the help .

Answer (score 1):

I have written some partial results about this problem, I hope it helps someone to find the solution.

Without loss of generality, $a\geq b \geq c$. Next, since $ab+bc+ac=1$, then at least one of them is less than $1/\sqrt{3}$, i.e., $c\leq 1/\sqrt{3}$. Otherwise, $ab+bc+ac>1$.

Similarly, $ab\leq ab+bc+ac \leq 1$, and hence if $b>1$, then $ab>1$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, $b\leq 1$.
Note also that as $bc\leq bc+ac+ab=1$,

\begin{equation}
     \frac{\sqrt{a+1}}{a+bc}\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+1}}
\end{equation}
Finally, combining all the results,
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\sqrt{a+1}}{a+bc}+\frac{\sqrt{b+1}}{b+ac}+\frac{\sqrt{c+1}}{c+ab}\geq \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{1+\sqrt{3}}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

*Here is another approach.*

By AM-GM, we have
$$\frac{\sqrt{a+1}}{a+bc}
= \frac{2(a+1)}{(a+bc)\cdot 2\sqrt{a + 1}} \ge \frac{2(a+1)}{(a+bc)\cdot \left(\frac{a + 1}{(\sqrt 2 - 1)a + 1} + (\sqrt 2 - 1)a + 1\right)}.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{2(a+1)}{(a+bc)\cdot \left(\frac{a + 1}{(\sqrt 2 - 1)a + 1} + (\sqrt 2 - 1)a + 1\right)} \ge 1 + 2\sqrt 2. \tag{1}$$
(1) is true which is verified by *Mathematica*.

Comment: Oh, you wrote my idea as an answer. Very nice, thank you.

Comment: @TATAbox Yes, the idea is similar to some problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea :

Transforming the sum into a product :

Let $c\in (0,1)$ define :

$$a=\frac{\left(1-xc\right)}{x+c},b=x$$

Then using AM-GM setting $d=\left|\frac{1}{\left(1-c\right)c}\right|$ **it seems** we have :

$$3\left(\left(\frac{\sqrt{a+1}}{a+bc}+\frac{d}{3}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{c+1}}{c+ab}+\frac{d}{3}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{b+1}}{b+ca}+\frac{d}{3}\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-d-\left(1+2\sqrt{2}\right)>0$$

Can someone confirm ?

Edit : the inequality is false like that but we can replace $d=\left|\frac{1}{\left(1-c\right)c}\right|$ by $d=\frac{1}{\left(1-c\right)^2c^2}$

Now I think it's true give me feed back

We have a really nice bound  which need to be simplify let $x\geq 0$ then we have :

$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{\left(1+\left(\frac{51}{2\sqrt{2}}-18\right)\right)\left(x+1\right)}{2+\frac{x}{6}-\frac{1}{\frac{x}{3}+1}}-\left(\frac{51}{2\sqrt{2}}-18\right)\left(1+\frac{x}{3}\right)-b\frac{x}{\left(x+3\right)^{3}}\left(\frac{2x}{x+1}-1\right)^{2}\left(3-x\right)-\sqrt{x+1}\leq 0$$

$b$ is defined as follow :

$$f'(3)=0,b\simeq 3/4$$

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea...

Let
\begin{equation}
    f(a,b,c)=\frac{\sqrt{a+1}}{a+bc}+\frac{\sqrt{b+1}}{b+ac}+\frac{\sqrt{c+1}}{c+ab}
\end{equation}
Then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial c}<0$ gives $ab<1+c$ which is true.  Similarly for partial derivatives with respect to $a$ and $b$. So the function is decreasing away from boundry. Without loss of generality, we can take $c=0$. Rest should be easy. We have two variables.

Comment: But there is a constraint $ab+bc+ca=1$. You cannot (e.g.) decrease $c$ while keeping the other variables constant.

Comment: @MartinR I thought without the constraint first then restricted on the constraint surface. My advanced calculus is not enough here.