Prove $\prod (1+a_i^2) \le \frac {2^n}{n^{2n-2}}\left (\sum a_i\right)^{2n-2}$ for positive reals $\prod a_i = 1$
Problem. Let $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 3}$. Let $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n > 0$ such that $\prod_{i=1}^n a_i = 1$. Prove that
$$\prod^n_{i=1} (1+a_i^2) \le \frac {2^n}{n^{2n-2}}\left (\sum^n_{i=1} a_i\right)^{2n-2}.$$
I saw this problem recently which was originally asked about 12 years ago
-- a Problem Statement Question (PSQ)
which will be closed. There were six answers.
Some users tackled the problem by the method of Lagrange Multipliers.
I am afraid once it was closed, some users can not see the Q&A there.
Hope to see nice proofs.
As an alternative way, my approach is given below.
Let
$$f(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n) := \frac {2^n}{n^{2n-2}}\left (\sum^n_{i=1} a_i\right)^{2n-2} - \prod^n_{i=1} (1+a_i^2).$$
Consider the minimum of $f$ subject to
$a_i > 0, \forall i$
and $\prod_{i=1}^n a_i = 1$.
It is easy to prove that the minimum exists (finite).
We claim that at minimum,
among $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n$, there are at most two distinct values.
Assume, for the sake of contraction, that
at minimum, there exists $a_i > a_j > a_k$.
We have the following identity
$$(1 + a_i^2)(1 + a_j^2)(1 + a_k^2)$$
$$= (a_i + a_j + a_k - a_i a_j a_k)^2
+ (a_i a_j + a_j a_k + a_k a_i - 1)^2.\tag{1}$$
To proceed, we need the following Fact 1.
Fact 1. Let $p, r > 0; p^3 > 27r$ be given. Let $a, b, c > 0$ such that $a+b+c = p$ and $abc = r$. Then
$ab + bc + ca$ is maximized only if $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a) = 0$,
and $ab + bc + ca$ is minimized only if $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a) = 0$.
(The proof is easy. Actually, it is a result in the uvw method.)
By Fact 1 and (1), there exist $x, y > 0$ such that
$a_i + a_j + a_k = 2x + y$, and $a_i a_j a_k = x^2y$,
and $(1 + a_i^2)(1 + a_j^2)(1 + a_k^2)
< (1 + x^2)(1 + x^2)(1 + y^2)$.
Thus, if we replace $a_i, a_j, a_k$ with $x, x, y$,
we have a strictly smaller objective value.
This contradicts the optimality of $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n$.
The claim is proved.
Thus, we can assume that $a_1 = a_2 = \cdots = a_k$,
and $a_{k+1} = a_{k+2} = \cdots = a_n$ for some $k$. The problem is reduced to the following.
Problem 1. Let $x, y > 0$ and $1 \le k \le n$ and $x^k y^{n-k} = 1$. Prove that
$$(1 + x^2)^k(1 + y^2)^{n-k}
\le \frac{2^n}{n^{2n-2}}(kx + (n-k)y)^{2n-2}.$$

People might get inspiration from the solution attempts to the original question, so here it is: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/223134/42969

@MartinR Thanks. I found it already appeared on the right sidebar after I posted my questions :).

After searching MSE, I found this question is the same as my Fact 1, and the answer is basically my idea. And the answer also linked to the question Martin R gave in the comment.

A complete proof proceeding along OP's lines
Let us prove the inequality in Problem 1.
(1) If $k = n$, clearly it is true.
(2) If $1 \le k \le n-1$, we have
$x = y^{-(n-k)/k}$, and it suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
 f(y) &:= \ln \left(\frac{2^n}{n^{2n-2}}\left(ky^{-(n-k)/k} + (n-k)y\right)^{2n-2}\right)\\
 &\qquad - \ln \left((1 + y^{-2(n-k)/k})^k(1 + y^2)^{n-k}\right)\\
 &\ge 0. \tag{1}
\end{align*}
We have
$$f'(y) = \frac{2(n-k)(y^{n/k}-1)}{y(y^2+1)(y^2+y^{2n/k})((n-k)y^{n/k} + k)}\cdot g(y, y^{n/k}),$$
where
$$g(y, z) := k{y}^{2}{z}^{2}+n{y}^{4}-n{y}^{2}z-{y}^{4}-{y}^{2}{z}^{2}-k{y}^{2}+n{y
}^{2}+n{z}^{2}-{y}^{2}-{z}^{2}.$$
It is not difficult to prove that
$g(y, z) > 0$ for all $y > 0, z \in \mathbb{R}$, given that $n \ge 3$ and $1 \le k \le n - 1$.
Thus, $g(y, y^{n/k}) > 0$.
Thus, $f'(y) < 0$ on $(0, 1)$, and $f'(y) > 0$ on $(1, \infty)$.
Thus, $f(y) \ge f(1) = 0$.
We are done.
